# Is there any way to download the html table just beside an svg along with the svg?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, html5-canvas

I am using d3.js to create a pie diagram to show the coverage of a particular industry and just beside the svg I have an html table to represent the different colors for different industries. I used canvas.toBlob() to download the svg as a png. Is there any way to download the html along with the svg.

```js
$('#downloadHeatMap')
        .click(
            function() {
                if (!isIE && (width > 32767 || height > 32767)) {
                    alert("Unable to download, Image width/height limit exceeded");
                } else if (isIE && (width > 8192 || height > 8192)) {
                    alert("Unable to download, Image width/height limit exceeded");
                } else if (isChrome && (width * height) > 268435456) {
                    alert("Unable to download, Image width/height limit exceeded");
                } else if (isFirefox && (width * height) > 472907776) {
                    alert("Unable to download, Image width/height limit exceeded");
                } else {
                 var html = d3.select("svg").attr("version", 1.1).attr(
                            "xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg").node().parentNode.innerHTML;
                 var svg = $('svg').parent().html();
                    var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
                    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    canvas.width = width + 100;
                    canvas.height = height + 50;
                    canvg(document.getElementById('drawingArea'), html);
                    canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
                       saveAs(blob, "heatMapDiagram.png");
                    });
                }
            });
```

Here is the table i have beside the svg

```html
<div class="pure-pusher-container">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 text-center">
     <h1 ><span class="pull-right">Industry Distribution Map</span></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
     <input type="button" value="Download Heatmap" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 20px;" id="downloadHeatMap">    
    </div>
   </div>
  
   <div class="row" style="margin-top: 40px;">
    <div class="col-md-10" id="heatMapDiv"><span class="pull-right" id="vis"></span></div>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="margin-top: 40px;">
      
      <table class="table">
       <thead>
                     <tr>
                         <th>Color</th>
                         <th >% Coverage</th>
                     </tr>
                     </thead>
                     <tbody>
                     <tr>
                      <td style="background-color:#FF4242;"></td>
                      <td> 0 </td>
                     </tr>
                     
                     <tr>
                         <td style="background-color:#B84C4C;"></td>
                         <td> 1 - 20</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                         <td style="background-color:#de783b;"></td>
                         <td> 21 - 40</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                         <td style="background-color:#BC9BE0;"></td>
                         <td> 41 - 60</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                         <td style="background-color:#5687d1;"></td>
                         <td> 61 - 80</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                         <td style="background-color:#6ab975;"></td>
                         <td> 81 - 100</td>
                     </tr>
                     </tbody>
                 </table>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Is there any way to save the html table along with my svg as a png ?

Comment: You could try [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases)

Answer (score 0):

First create a DOM element that contains both the table and the chart, side by side. Then you can use the [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html) JavaScript library to screenshot that entire DOM element into a canvas element, and then download it as a png to the user's computer:

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById("yourContainerID"), {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
        saveAs(blob, "heatMapDiagram.png");
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi. I need the table along with the pie diagram. I think i used the same to download my svg as png.

Comment: @user3531436 Ah. In that case you will want to create an element containing both the table and the the chart, then use html2canvas on the whole thing.